# ¿Como realizar un condicional en php con elementos de archivo html?

Tags: php, html

Tengo un archivo html en el cual quiero aplicar un filtro para una búsqueda. En esta opción de filtro se encuentran unos botones los cuales representan las valoraciones de 1 a 5 estrellas de un local. a cada botón le puse un id para diferenciarlos y lo que quiero es que cuando elija alguno de los botones y aplique el filtro, en el archivo action_page.php se modifique la variable de valoración para que este valor sea luego consultado en el query de búsqueda de locales.

Mi archivo html index tiene lo siguiente:

```
<form class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php" method="post">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    <div class="container">
      <p><b>Valoracion</b></p>
      <button id="b1" class="button-34 noShadow">
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      </button>
      <button id="b2" class="button-34 noShadow">
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      </button>
      <button id="b3" class="button-34 noShadow">
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      </button>
      <button id="b4" class="button-34 noShadow">
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      </button>
      <button id="b5" class="button-34 noShadow">
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
<div class="container flex justify-between " style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="button-34">Cancelar</button>
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="button-34">Apicar filtro</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Acá los botones tienen id igual a b1, b2, b3, b4 y b5. Ahora en el archivo action_page.php:

```
<php
$Valoracion=0;
if(id del boton es igual a b1){
$Valoracion=1;
}else if(id del boton es igual a b2){
$Valoracion=2;
}
?>
```

Apenas estoy empezando a aprender con php y no sabría como realizar estos condicionales. Necesito saber como llamar el archivo index y así llamar los id de los botones para alterar el valor de la variable "Valoracion" para cuando realice el query en la base de datos, este query consulte si el valor de valoración del local en la tabla es igual al valor de valoración en el archivo action_page y así muestre únicamente según el filtro aplicado.

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Este tipo de cosas hoy día se hacen con Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript. Es simple: escuchas los clicks de los botones, mandas al servidor el id del botón que fue presionado y luego en el servidor lanzas la consulta a la BD o lo que sea y devuelves los datos al cliente (HTML). Y todo eso de una forma transparente, sin tener que recargar la página y sin mezclar entornos, cada cosa de su lado: cliente y servidor.

Comment: Como dice @A.Cedano, lo más sencillo es ocupar Ajax, te recomiendo que empieces a ver,  como puedes enviar datos del front a tu backend, Con POST y GET. Empieza por aprender como funcionan los formularios, si te avientas a hacer estos proyectos con muy poco conocimientos te vas a frustrar mucho. Traza una pequeña ruta de aprendizaje.

Comment: Por otro lado si aún asi deseas crear el proyecto te recomiendo este tutorial, donde hacen todo lo que necesitas a un nivel un poco más avanzado. https://www.webslesson.info/2021/05/how-to-create-review-rating-page-in-php-with-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tendrías que hacer en tu archivo index cambiarlo por index.php dentro del cual vas a usar las mismas etiquetas html y de paso el contenido de tu archivo action, agregarlo a este mismo index.php

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).